# Traversing children of siblings in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the background image of a radio button when it is checked. I have hidden the radio button and wrapped it inside a `label>span>img`. I want to change the src of the image when the radio is checked.

```
<div class = " monthly-radio-div padding-lr-zero radio-inline">
   <input type="radio"  name="inv_type" id="monthly" value = "monthly" >
   <label for="monthly">
      <span class="radio">
         <img src="icons/r_dis.png">
      </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

I want to change the src of the image. I tried few ways which didn't work

```
$('#fund_sel_form input').on('change', function() {
    var radio_val = $('input[name="inv_type"]:checked', '#fund_sel_form').val(); 
    $('input[name="inv_type"]:checked','#fund_sel_form').find('label').find('img').attr('src','icons/r_en.png');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this working fiddle [jsfiddle.net/s1f891vn/](https://jsfiddle.net/s1f891vn/)

```
$('.monthly-radio-div input').on('change', function() {
    var parentDiv=$(this).parents(".monthly-radio-div:eq(0)");
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(parentDiv).find("img").attr("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-on-128.png");
    }
    else{
        $(parentDiv).find("img").attr("src","https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/toggle/512/radio-off-128.png");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.monthly-radio-div > input').on('change', function() {
    var par =$(this).parents().eq(0);
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(parentDiv).find("img").attr("src","image.png");
    }
    else{
        $(parentDiv).find("img").attr("src","image.png");
    }
});
```